# altool exists in Xcode's Versions/A/Support folder, and Current/Folder. What is the difference?

Tags: xcode, application-loader

I want to write a script that consistently references the correct version of Application Loader.  I plan to use [Altool to automatically load the app into the App Store](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf)

In that document it says:

> To validate your build before upload or to automate uploads of valid builds to the App Store, you can include altool in your continuous integration systems. altool is located in the Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/ folder.

I see the ALTool in both

- /Versions/A/Support/
- /Versions/Current/Support/

What is the difference between the instances of the bundled tool?

Why would the documentation refer to "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Current` is a soft link to `A`. In theory there could be a `B`, `C`, etc. and `Current` would point to the "current" version.

Generally, go through `Current` to get the current version. Go through `A` (or one of the others) to get that specific version.